# Drag and drop issues in angular 1.5

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, drag-and-drop

I have a div and it is a draggable element. It should drop on a component while dragging we should show the number where it is dropping. I do attached screen shot.

I am using angular directive to drag and drop and here is the below code. I just wanted to know I am able to fire `showLineEffect` method from directive but `dropProperties` is not getting updated in UI but in console it is showing updated values while dragging.

I tried with `ng-mouseover` event but its not working when we hold and element. Please let me know if there is any other solution.

Controller:

```
var vm= this;
    vm.dropProperties = {
            showLine: false,
            indentLeft: 0,
            indentRight: 0,
            totalWidth: 10,
            totalHeight: 32,
            startMonth: 0
        };

    vm.showLineEffect = function (event) {
            vm.dropProperties.showLine = true;
            vm.dropProperties.startMonth = Math.round((event.clientX - 160) / 48);
            console.log($ctrl.dropProperties +"changed");

        }
```

Directive:

```
app.directive('dragOppSol',
function dragOppSol() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            element.prop('draggable', true);
            element.on('dragstart', function (event) {
            console.log("drag started");
                //event.dataTransfer.setData('text', event.target.id)
            });
        }
    };
}
);
app.directive('dropOppSol',
function dropOppSol() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            element.on('dragover', function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                //console.log("test change" + scope.ctrl.dropProperties.startMonth);
                scope.ctrl.showLineEffect(event);



                // Implementation of CSS

            });
            element.on('drop', function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();


            });
        }
    };
});
```

[image: dropped image]

Answer (score 1):

Add `$scope.$apply()` after scope.ctrl.showLineEffect(event); or in vm.showLineEffect.

$scope.$apply ~~tells angular that it should check and update all html bindings.

Any ng-smth, like ng-click, ng-mouseover, ng-keydown... simply does:

```
eval_and_run(expression)
$scope.$apply()
```